# Getting button from one view controller in other view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation, uibutton

I'm total newbie in ios programming so it generates a lot of problems. 
I have 2 controllers - SwitchingViewController and ToastViewController. SwitchingViewController is switching between controllers, so it also have a buttons.

Now the point is - how to show button "back", declarated in SwitchingViewController, in ToastViewController?

It looks like that

SwitchingViewController.h

```
@interface SwitchingViewController : UIViewController{
  IBOutlet UIButton *addnew;
  IBOutlet UIButton *contin;
  IBOutlet UIButton *mytoasts;
  IBOutlet UIButton *backToToast;
}
```

ToastViewController.m

```
#import "SwitchingViewController.h"

@interface ToastViewController ()
@end

@implementation ToastViewController
  -(void)sendToServer:(id)sender{
    //show here backToToast button
  }
```

I tried something like [SwitchViewController.backToToast] or getByTag but it obviously doesn't work (I have experience in ruby, so I have lot of after-effects).
Can somebody tell me how to manipulate elements from other controllers?

**EDIT/solved**

Actually I did this reversing the problem... I put a button in ToastViewController, for example *goToBack and connect it with action sendToServer. Now when goToBack is cliked, it runs sendToServer action, which looks like:

```
//do somenthing to send to server and change view to other controller
//changing controller is defined in action goBackToOther in SwitchViewController

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"goBackToOtherNotif" object: nil];
```

and in SwitchViewController.m -> init()

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(goBackToOther:) name: @"goBackToOtherNotif" object: nil];
```

in SwitchViewController.m -> dealloc()

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Maybe it's not very elegant, but like I said - I'm not familiar with ios programming yet, so I take what works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create Properties in SwitchingViewController.h and synthesize backToToast in SwitchingViewController.m file.

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backToToast; (SwitchingViewController.h)

@synthesize backToToast; (SwitchingViewController.m)

Comment: But in this situation I can only use it in SwitchingViewController, right? I need to show this button in other controller